# Is GHC.Arr a good enough Array implementation to use?

Tags: arrays, haskell

I'm on a platform where only `base` is available, no other library. I'd like to use the Array data structure. I can't use Data.Array which is defined in a separate package in `array`.

I found GHC.Arr provides array implementation. Is it a good implementation to use?

I was also wondering why the documentation for `GHC.Arr` doesn't have a link 
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0

Comment: Are you sure you can't import the `Data.Array` module? It's specified in [Haskell2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellpa2.html#haskellch14.html), I'd be really surprised if some Haskell distribution didn't have it.

Comment: Nice. Thank you Chris. I was doing google code jam 2018. [And it says the Haskell's complier's version is 8.0.1 and package is `ghc`](https://code.google.com/codejam/resources/faq). I've no idea what packages are included there. How can I find document that lists all the modules included in the package `ghc`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc, you can see that the `ghc` package has a dependency on the `array` package, so it is probably available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [code jam site](https://code.google.com/codejam/resources/faq#language-details):

> Our platform uses 64-bit Debian 9.3 (stretch). We install the packages using the command `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends {.package_name}`.
>
> [...]
>
> Haskell:
>
> - The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System 8.0.1 (package: `ghc`)
> - `ghc +RTS -V0 -RTS -rtsopts -o Solution Solution.hs`
> - `./Solution +RTS -V0 -RTS`

So, the list of installed files can be found at https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/ghc/filelist .

Standard Haskell packages such as `base,array,containers,...` are included. You can use `Data.Array`.

Full list of packages:

```
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/Cabal-1.24.0.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/array-0.5.1.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/base-4.9.0.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/binary-0.8.3.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/bytestring-0.10.8.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/containers-0.5.7.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/deepseq-1.4.2.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/directory-1.2.6.2.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/filepath-1.4.1.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/ghc-8.0.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/ghc-boot-8.0.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/ghc-boot-th-8.0.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/ghci-8.0.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/haskeline-0.7.2.3.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/hoopl-3.10.2.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/hpc-0.6.0.3.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/pretty-1.1.3.3.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/process-1.4.2.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/rts.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/template-haskell-2.11.0.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/terminfo-0.4.0.2.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/time-1.6.0.1.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/transformers-0.5.2.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/unix-2.7.2.0.conf
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/xhtml-3000.2.1.conf
```